# Drag and Drop List in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have created this list using basic HTML and jQuery.  This is just a test for a larger project, but it does not appear to be working.

I have a .css page, an html page, and a .js page, and they should all be functioning together.

Here is the HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>JQuery Drag List Test</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="title" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/testingcolumns.css"></link>

</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li class="item">Coffee</li>
  <li class="item">Tea</li>
  <li class="item">Milk</li>
</ul> 

<div id="list"></div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jq/dragdrop.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jq/jq-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jq/jq-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li').draggable({
        containment: 'document',
        revert: true,
        start: function() {
            contents = $(this).text();
        }
    });


    $('#list').droppable({
        hoverClass: 'border',
        accept: '.item',
        drop: function() {
            $('#list').append(contents + ' <br /> ');
        }
    });

});​
```

This is the CSS

```
ul {
width: 150px;
padding: 0px;
list-style: none;
}

#list {

width: 120px;
height: 180px;
background-color: #0F9;
border: 1px solid #000;
overflow: auto;
 }

#list.border {
border-width: 2px;
}
```

All together this should be working, but for some reason when I use Dreamweaver to preview in browser the 3 list elements appear as bullet points and list (which appears as a greenbox in dreamweaver) does not appear at all.  The bullet points will not drag in the browser.

Comment: Can you throw this into a JSFiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ is a website that allows you to add pieces of html, javascript and css and then see how it will render.  In this situation you could all the pieces from above (you will need to change the path to your JS files to something global) and then paste the link here.  This will allow people to see what you are talking about and "fiddle" with your code to see if they can fix it.  It's a great tool!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rGjv7/

It still didn't work.

Comment: I mean the fiddle worked, but the code is still not.  Any insight would still be helpful.

Comment: Well the fiddle won't magically fix it... It's just for showing your issue to people.

Comment: Could you explain what the desired functionality is?

Comment: I know it won't fix it, I was hoping that maybe the browser wasn't displaying it accurately.  The desired functionality is to simply drag the items from the list over to the green box.

Comment: Where did you get dragdrop.js? Since you are using a relative path in your fiddle, it's not finding that.  Do you know of a full URL path to that file?

Comment: Same thing with the other two js files you included.

Comment: You should post the answer here in case someone else runs into it.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching the order you are including JS files in your page from:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jq/dragdrop.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jq/jq-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jq/jq-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jq/jq-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jq/jq-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jq/dragdrop.js"></script>
```

I don't know what dragdrop.js is, but if it's using jQuery or jQuery UI that could be your problem.